# Adding boot sound to Froyo 2.2 Droid

Tags: android, audio, boot, android-2.2-froyo

I have been attempting to add sound on boot to run with the boot animation on a droid running Froyo 2.2 ROM.

This is what I have tried this far:

Added to init.rc

```
###Bootsound - Safe to Delete: Start ###

service bootsound /system/bin/bootsound
        user media
        group audio
        disabled
        oneshot

on property:init.svc.bootanim=running   # to correct timing
        start bootsound

on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
        stop bootsound
### Bootsound - Safe to Delete: End ###
```

Created bootsound in /system/bin

```
#!/system/bin/sh
#bootsound - plays a sound at boot

bprop=/system/build.prop
grepprop() { x=`grep "^$1=" $bprop | head -n 1`; echo $x | cut -d = -f 2; }

play=`grepprop "ro.config.play.bootsound"`

if [ "$play" = "1" ]; then
        stagefright -a -o /system/media/android_audio.mp3
fi
exit 0
```

Added to build.prop

```
### Safe to Delete: Start ###
ro.config.play.bootsound=1
### Safe to Delete: End ###
```

And of course added the android_audio.mp3 file to /system/media

No luck, can anyone spot what I may have missed?

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up seeing this approach work?

Answer (score 1):

First English translator, I apologize for using the single point.
 While attempting to see your post when applied to Android 2.3 GingerBread bootsound have found the problem really happen organically.
 Bootsound during the Boot Device, the following error was encountered.

bootsound: 12: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")

Device is being used currently the LG Optimus Black (Android 2.3 Gingerbread)